# Login to account or sign up

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that allows a user to enter in a username and a password on the first visit and save those to external files. This is working on its ow, but I want the program to skip straight to login if text is found in the external files, as it means they already have an account. Then the user logs in and the program compares it with the data in the external files and only continues until correct username and password is entered.

I have tried to type the code but these errors come up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 27, in <module>
    login()
line 16, in login
    check()
line 19, in check
    if username == open("username").read() and passsword == open("password").read():
NameError: name 'username' is not defined
```

```
def make_account():

    filename = ("username");
    with open (filename, "w") as f:
      f.write (input("Enter a username: "));

    filename = ("password");
    with open (filename, "w") as f:
      f.write (input("Enter a password: "));


def login():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    check()

def check():
    if username == open("username").read() and passsword == open("password").read():
        print("Successful login")
    else:
        print('Incorrect')


import os.path
if os.path.exists("username"):
    login()
else:
    make_account()
```

Comment: `username` is not defined in `check()`'s scope.

Answer (score 2):

`username` and `password` are not in scope in the `check` function. You need to pass them in:

```
def login():
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    check(username, password) # note: passing in here

def check(username, password): # accept the parameters here
    if username == open("username").read() and password == open("password").read():
        print("Successful login")
    else:
        print('Incorrect')
```